# IE shows Error Code 11001: Host not found after starting fiddler

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

I am trying to browse to an intranet site using IE 8.0

it works fine when fiddler is not started.

However once fiddler is started and the same URL is browsed in IE, then error message as shown below comes up

> Error Code 11001: Host not found  Background: This error indicates
>   that the gateway could not find the IP address of the website you are
>   trying to access. This is usually due to a DNS-related error.

Fiddler shows the error as 502

Is this due to fiddler settings and how do I fix it

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Fiddler->WinInet options->Connections tab->click Lan settings button->Check the checkbox for "use a proxy server for...."->Click OK in subsquent screens.

Restart fiddler

Hope this will be useful for someone else in future.